# How to set a mac app's working directory instead of my home directory?

Tags: mac, applications, startup

I want to start a Mac app in a particular directory.  For example IDLE.  It starts in my home directory but I want it to start in my `/users/peter/Documents/py` directory.

Windows has the ability let you edit the link and choose a start up directory.  Some Linux distros also let you chose a startup directory/working directory. Mac OS does not, at least I haven't found it yet.

Is there some file in the resources section of the Mac apps folder that can be edited or a file in the user Library that can be edited to due the equivalent of `cd /Users/peter/Documents/py` automatically?

I have looked in `/Users/peter/Library/Application Scripts` and in
`/Users/peter/Application/Support` and have found nothing.  I did try making a `init.py` file in `/Users/peter/Library/Application Support` but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any hints?

Comment: "I want to start a Mac app in a particular directly" Do you mean "directory"?

Comment: See the StackOverflow post on this topic:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1425092